# install scala 2.12 mac with homebrew

Tags: scala, installation, homebrew

I'd like to install the latest version of Scala => version 2.12.0-M5 on my mac using homebrew.   Is it possible?

When I run command this is what I get

```
 brew install scala
 Warning: scala-2.11.6 already installed
```

Answer (score 1):

$ brew remove scala 
$ brew install scala --devel

Comment: `No devel block is defined for scala`

Comment: Works On My Computer (TM) ! `==> Downloading http://www.scala-lang.org/files/archive/scala-2.12.0-M5.tgz`

Answer (score 0):

https://gist.github.com/dimetron/4340744
This might solve your problem  Thanks !

Comment: @richs : If your problem is resolved please paste the method and please accept the answer !

Comment: Just executing the steps in the link won't install scala 2.12. The .rb script has hardcoded older version of scala. The script will require some changes to make it work for scala 2.12 .